# Assigning a value in a variable

Tags: awk

I need assign into a variable a value using awk:

```
$ echo "hello world" | awk -v x=substr($0,3,4) '{print $x}'
 -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

What's wrong here ?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to do is

```
$ echo "hello world" | awk '{print substr($0,3,4)}'  

llo
```

substr is an awk function and only available in the awk script (inside the quotes)

Or, assigning it to a variable

```
$ awk -v x='hello world' 'BEGIN{print substr(x,3,4)}'   

llo
```